# Java alternative for scipy butterworth bandpass filter

Tags: java, signal-processing, audio-processing

I am trying to bandpass some audio frequencies and I have successfully implemented and have got the correct results from scipy.signal module in python. But my necessity is to do that in java so that I can do some filtering in android.

I tried using [berndporr/iirj](https://github.com/berndporr/iirj) library in java but it returns the data as it originally was. Here is the code in java using this library. The `list` is a double array containing the audio samples.

```
double[] filteredList = new double[list.length];
Butterworth butterworth = new Butterworth();
butterworth.bandPass(3,44100,110,90);
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    filteredList[i] = butterworth.filter(list[i]);
}
```

The `filteredList` does not match with the output of my python program which is using scipy.

The python code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, filter

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

arr = np.array(list)

filteredList = butter_bandpass_filter(arr, 20, 200, 44100, order=3)
```

Here the `filteredList` contains the correct output.
I am comparing the results with output from FL studio which is applying a 20hz-200hz bandpass filter.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my Java code or can anyone tell me a better library for audio filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For audio filtering in Android, there is a standard [equalizer AudioEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) library that looks usable.

FWIW, Java is a painful language to do signal processing in. If you need something beyond Android's AudioEffects, consider using Android NDK and writing in C++.

Comment: This standard android equalizer only affects predefined frequency bands. For example on the phone on which I am testing my android app the first band goes from 20hz to 460 hz and the second goes to 460hz to 1500hz. But I want to band pass frequencies from 50 hz to 1500 hz, so the android official library is of no use to me(I would be happy to be proven wrong in this case).

Comment: Can you recommend any c++ library for band pass filtering on a wav file

Comment: You might try [multichannel-audio-tools](https://github.com/google/multichannel-audio-tools). Particularly, IIR filter design functions for Chebyshev, etc. are in   [biquad_filter_design.h](https://github.com/google/multichannel-audio-tools/blob/master/audio/linear_filters/biquad_filter_design.h) and applied using `BiquadFilterCascade` in [biquad_filter.h](https://github.com/google/multichannel-audio-tools/blob/master/audio/linear_filters/biquad_filter.h).